# Is there a Konsole equivalent for gnome?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome, konsole

I'm looking for a Konsole equivalent for Gnome.  I searched Google but was surprised how little I found.

I don't want a Quake-style dropdown console.  I like tabs and the ability to send a command to all tabs.  Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with using Konsole in Gnome?

Answer (score 1):

The default terminal for Gnome is gnome-terminal, and it does support tabs.

When it comes to sending command to multiple servers at once, how about **[ClusterSSH](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/clusterssh/index.php?title=Main_Page)**?

[image]

Comment: but i dont see a way to send a command to all tabs... :(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out [Compiz](http://www.compiz.org/), which is definitely one of the best looking X-Window managers I've seen in a while. If you're more of a minimalist then [IceWM](http://www.icewm.org/) is another option; it's lightweight and highly customizable. The X-Window manager for Gnome 3 ([Mutter](http://www.ohloh.net/p/mutter)) is nice looking too, although some say it's bloated and no tabs that I'm aware.

- [Comparison of X-Window Managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_window_managers)

Comment: @ zds: I think he might have guessed that already.

@ digitxp: Konsole is a KDE component; unless KDE is installed it won't work, and doing would defeat the purpose of running Gnome.

Comment: Looking into apt on Ubuntu, Konsole only depends on the KDE runtime and some qt libraries. Nothing that would make the massive behemoth that is GNOME any slower.

Answer (score 0):

I like [ROXTerm](http://roxterm.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=installation&lang=en). Has tabbing, Customizable profiles, the works. Plus its super lightweight.